# JPA How to persist a Map<enum, Set<String>>

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, jpa

I'd like to persist emails in an Oracle database using annotations. My `Email` class has a Map property `recipients`, which is grouped by TO, CC and BCC and has a Set of email addresses as values:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMAIL")
public class Email {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="emailSeq", sequenceName="EMAIL_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="emailSeq")
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id = null;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Set.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "emailrecipients", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="email_id"))
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="address")
    private Map<RecipientType, Set<String>> recipients = new HashMap<RecipientType, Set<String>>();
    ...
}

public enum RecipientType {
    TO,
    CC,
    BCC
}
```

My database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE email
( id number(10) NOT NULL,
  ...
  CONSTRAINT email_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE emailrecipients
( email_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  --Addresstypes: "TO", "CC", "BCC"
  addresstype varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  address varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_emailrecipients_email FOREIGN KEY (email_id) REFERENCES email(id)
);
```

I'm having trouble to do the mapping properly and I'm getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: emailrecipients, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(address)]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add `emailrecipients` table also

Comment: Nope you cannot persist a map value of type `Collection`. No JPA doc would ever do that. You could define an `AttributeConverter` for the map value to convert it into something persistable

Comment: @AbinashGhosh I already have an `emailrecipients` table. Did you mean I have to add something to my Java code or change the aanotations? Could you please be a bit more specific (I'm a newbie to JPA/Hibernate)?

Comment: @drjones add your Java code for `emailrecipients` table

Comment: @AbinashGhosh I don't have a Java class `emailrecipients` at all. I thought I would not need to for basic/collection types. Maybe my annotations are wrong... I'm open to suggestions of refactoring my Java code, if a Map<enumtype, Set<String>> cannot be persisted using JPA at all like @BillyFrost considered. BTW: I cannot figure out, how an AttributeConverter might help me out, since the problem of persisting a Set of email addresses for each of TO, CC and BCC is still the same, isn't it?